# Tracking X value of hand from leap motion in processing

Tags: processing, leap-motion

```java
ArrayList<PVector> pointss; 
PVector fp; 

 for (Hand hand : leap.getHands()) {
    for (Finger finger : hand.getFingers()) {
       fp   = finger.getPosition(); 
    }
 }
```

In the project I'm working on, I need to replace the `mouseX` variable with the X variable generated by the leap motion for hand tracking. It tracks the hand with [X, Y, Z] but since I need to save the variable that holds this data as a `PVector` I am not sure how to get the X variable out of it.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a `PVector` instance, you can simply reference its `x` field.

```java
PVector p = new PVector(100, 200, 300);
println(p.x); //prints 100
```

More info can be found in [the reference](https://processing.org/reference/PVector.html).

Comment: And if your question is how to get the x component of a Leap.Vector object, use: vector.getX(); 
(https://developer.leapmotion.com/documentation/java/api/Leap.Vector.html#javaclasscom_1_1leapmotion_1_1leap_1_1_vector_1ae8f033a71b96920114aee202798dc7e9)

Comment: Sorry I didn't respond sooner, been really busy. I gave what Kevin suggest a try and was not able to get it to work. I think what Charles said is the tool I need to use, but I'm still a bit new to processing and after tinkering with it a bit I'm still not able to get it to work. I'm going to link the bit of code I'm using to show you what I'm dealing with and hopefully you can give me a hand. I'd really appreciate it! Just look at my main post for the code

Comment: @Unscrupulous If `fp` is a `PVector` then you can just use `fp.x` to get its `x` component. What exactly do you mean when you say it doesn't work?

Comment: When I use fp.x I get a nullpointerexception error. I did some research for the error and there doesn't seem to be a real solution.

Comment: Was able to figure it out, thanks for eveyrones help